# Each new light bulb for my oven doesn't last long

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, appliances, oven

The light bulb in my Whirlpool WFG231LVS0 oven keeps burning out.  I've replaced it several times, with new bulbs of several different brands (all marked as being appropriate for ovens).

The new bulbs seem to work for a week or two and then stop turning on.

It seems like the filament is broken. As I rotate it around (see the gif below), I can hear something inside.

[image]

I've read elsewhere that oven lights often stop working either because of slamming doors damaging the filaments or because of liquid splattering onto them. I don't think that's the case with mine.

How can I diagnose and fix this problem?

P.S. This is not a new oven, and there had been more than a year of normal usage before this problem started happening.

Comment: Does it shake or vibrate at all?  I assume you've verified the bulbs are "really dead"?

Comment: @rogerdpack I updated my question with a gif. Yep, I think the bulbs are really dead. I hear a slight sound when I rotate the bulb.

Comment: Test your bulb socket to see if it is over powered. I could see a darker spot on the bulb, so its seems to be getting too much power, over voltage.

Comment: Yup I can see the broken filament in a frame of the video.  With clear bulbs it’s often possible to simply look at the filament to see if it’s broken.  Even in ovens, I’ve seen bad sockets producing heat cause premature bulb failure.

Comment: Is it a 3-wire or 4-wire connection to the service? Is anyone getting shock off the chassis?

Comment: Does the voltage seem "normal" to the bulb? (I meant "does the oven shake or near something that vibrates" though I can't imagine that being common...)

Comment: @Harper I don't know what  your questions mean. If the 2nd question is asking whether anyone has been shocked: no, nobody has been shocked by anything.

Comment: @JeffCates I can research how to do what you're suggesting. Then, if there *is* too much voltage now (when there wasn't before, since this oven had been fine for a long time), what would you say is the root cause and resolution? Thanks.

Comment: @rogerdpack There is no vibration that we're aware of.

Comment: I would check your breakers for the stove as well as if there are any fuses for the 120v portion of the stove (clock, timers, lights, etc.) Has any wiring been done around that area recently? Also, the lamp socket could be bad. Some are metal (usually aluminum) or ceramic. It could just need a socket adjustment, center pin of the socket pulled out to ensure a complete and solid connection to the bulb, or a replacement.

Comment: @JeffCates We did have a new, bigger air conditioning unit installed outside our kitchen on 2018-06-28. That's the only change I can think of. I wonder if that's somehow related. Thanks for these thoughts.

Comment: Is that about the same time the bulbs started burning out?

Comment: @JeffCates My partner and I don't know *exactly* when they starting burning out, but yes, we would have guessed within the past 2-3 months.

Comment: I would check out the bulb socket, it could be loose. But wouldn't rule out the wiring changes. Only way to find out if its the A/C is when the A/C is not used as much, say late fall thru early spring. Perhaps try turning off the circuit breaker to the A/C during that time and test a new bulb.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter?  I would be keen to know the voltage between oven chassis and a ground screw or pin on a kitchen receptacle, if you can find a bare metal part of the oven, under three conditions a) oven light on, b) range "burner" turned on, and c) A/C operating.  Warning, possibility of shock if I'm right.

Comment: Better still would be screw a 2-prong socket adapter into the lightbulb socket, run a 2-wire extension cord out of the oven, and measure the voltage between hot and neutral as the A/C cycles and while trying out a stove burner and also messing with the oven clock/ timer.   The voltage staying 120V would be a "pass", the voltage going all over the place from 80 to 140V would be a "fail".  We are testing the integrity of the oven's neutral wire. Neutral on an oven powers the oven light, timer and clock.  In 3-wire oven connections, it also **grounds the oven**, hence, shock risk.

Comment: I was on one job where lights would flicker wherever a new industrial grade dishwasher was turned on. Problem there was a loose neutral terminal in the panel for the dishwasher. Depending on your comfort level with electrical, verify screws and connections are tight in the panel. It might be more to your liking to call your local electrician in.

Comment: @Ryan - Have at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciated everyone's comments and wanted to follow up with what seems to be the answer.

My latest bulb has not burned out, and it has been 10+ months.

Apparently I'd simply had a streak of bad luck with the bulbs I'd bought.

[My hypothesis](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147813/oven-light-bulb-keeps-blowing-burning-out?noredirect=1#comment243391_147813) that my usage or lack of usage of air conditioning in various seasons affected the electricity of the oven seems to be incorrect.

Thanks for all the tips you posted, though.